# What does "stop whacking off" mean?

Tags: expressions, slang

Today my boss came by my desk and told to me

> *"stop whacking off, when will phase 2 of the project be completed?"*

What does "stop whacking off" mean?  I did not know how to respond.

What is an appropriate response?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually, if you don't know the meaning of a sentence, I would recommend a good dictionary, like [Merriam–Webster's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster's_Dictionary), or dictionary.com. There is an alternative dictionary, called "Urban Dictionary" where all of the definitions come from online users, and so it tends to get a lot of rude and slang words. In this case, this site has a great definition for [whacking-off:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whacking+off)

> Noun to describe the process of masturbating.

So your boss was rudely saying that what you were being unproductive instead of working, as if you were masturbating at work. Although to be fair, masturbating at work is *far* worse than merely unproductive, so in this case it's probably a lot closer to saying you were [slacking off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/slack-off), which just means not working as hard as you should be (it even rhymes!).

The appropriate response probably depends on whether or not you're offended by this remark. If you're not offended by his rough language, the appropriate response is probably to work harder. If you are, that might be a better question on the [workplace.se](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: No need to resort to Urban DIctionary; you can find this definition [in M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whack%20off), [in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/whack-off), [and in ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whack-off).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am happy to get such honest feedback from you.  Yes, I thought that "whacking off" maybe means "slacking off" but did not know that it really means masturbation.  What unkind words from my boss.

Comment: @user31113 it doesn't necessarily need to be unkind. It's vulgar language and familiar, but friends who like to joke around can say that as well and not get offended. It totally depends on your dynamics with your boss I guess.

Comment: Surely it is a verb, not a noun?

Comment: @user31113 I agree with Tyress - if your boss is a fluent native speaker then it could be that he was just being rude and abrasive *or* it could also be that he feels friendly enough with you that he can be this casual in joking around.  The tone of delivery will be the biggest signal here - it should be pretty clear if he was just having fun or if he was being rude.  If, however, your boss is not a native speaker then it could be that he is just using the phrase inappropriately - playing with casual English but not fully understanding the weight of the phrase he is using.

Comment: @user31113 it *is* crude, but situationally, this is metaphorical, not literal usage. I also think that "slacking off" is not quite right. The metaphorical intent can refer to paralysis by analysis, perfectionism, busywork, "spinning your wheels", or any form of work that even may create value, but that does not actually finish the work. Your boss obviously just wants you done. I would try not to be offended.

Comment: Whether anything can or should be done about the situation is a question for [workplace.se] as DJ has suggested, but that kind of language in a professional environment is really wrong. Would it be OK if a co-worker said "quit sucking his dick and stand up to him?" It's the same level of vulgar as whacking-off. The ideas expressed in the other comments that "it's OK if he's just joking around" or "try not to be offended" are frankly bullshit. @user31113 Using that expression at the office reflects very poorly on your boss.

Comment: @Colleen - I'm not disagreeing with you; you have a valid point. But language is tricky in this way. Someone might say, "Stop screwing around," which is another phrase with vulgar overtones, yet it's come to have its own meaning, too, to the point where some might consider it brusque but acceptable.

Comment: @J.R. You're right, but whacking-off is not one of those phrases. There is a "bro" culture that thinks gay is a synonym for lame, and fag is a synonym for loser, and those guys think whacking-off is a synonym for "messing around". Maybe some folks are ignorant of what kind of impression that language makes. Most of the time though I think those boys know it's wrong but they have friends that talk like that and are conflicted. The only way it makes it into polite vernacular is if people tolerate it, and I think that would be a mistake.